# How to default field based on project-level settings in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, project-management

I need to set a field on all User Stories, and that field will be the same for all stories within a project. Namely, I'm trying to assign projects to certain Project Leads and I want them to be defaulted as the Project Lead on all the user stories withing that project. How do I create a rule that will default a custom identity field to be the same for all user stories within that project? I'd rather not create a new Azure process for each new project. I want to be able to manually set some field on each project at the project level, and then have the default on my custom field in user stories within that project to be based on that project-level setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this can't be done through process customization. Unless you create a custom process for each project.

The [Aggregator-CLI](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli) can process a rule after a work-item is created/updated and you can use it to set these default values based on a lookup.

[This one-click extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mohitbagra.witoneclickactions) also makes it possible to run rules on the workitem form itself. It takes a different approach (runs in UI instead of from a servicehook).